# Drupal Views Field: Relationship Type B-to-A?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, relationships

I'm creating blocks to show a Drupal user's relationships on their user page. I've been able to create the views necessary to show the Display Names of the contacts in both the user's A to B relationships and of B to A relationships.  I'd like to display the name of the relationship as well for each contact. **There is a Views Field for Relationship Type A-to-B, but I can't find a Relationship Type B-to-A field. Any ideas?** If one does not exist or cannot be created by tweaking something in the Views UI, how would I go about creating the field in code?

Drupal 7.41, CiviCRM 4.6.6, CiviCRM_Entity module 2.x

Comment: Agree it looks like it doesn't exist and can't be 'influenced' by applying the relationship to that field. You could see if starting with a View based on Relationships doesn't trip you up somewhere else. I will fire this off at Torrance and see if he can give you a quick 'how to' for patching this.

Comment: Thank you Pete, that would be great and much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that not all fields from the CiviCRM RelationshipType entity are available in the the views by default. The socialistic party in the Netherlands had the same problem. And I created a drupal module for them to fix this.

You can find the module at https://github.com/SPnl/nl.sp.drupal-civicrm-views-enhancement

This module adds the name-a-b, label-a-b, name-b-a, label-b-a, contact-type-a, contact-type-b, contact-sub-type-a, contact-sub-type-b, description, is-reserved, is-active to drupal views.

Comment: Sounds great Jaap - what chance of this getting provided back to core as a patch?

Comment: I don't have a plan to do that. However feel free to reuse the code for a core patch.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, this fixed it for me, but I'd be interested in taking my coding skills up a notch and learning how to patch this in so others can benefit.  Where would this code need to go for a patch?  Into Civi Core (where?), the CiviCRM_Entity module, or some other place?  I'm willing to do the work, just need a little direction. :)

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to report this as an issue in the issue tracker at https://issues.civicrm.org Then you have to set up a local development environment. I have written a blog on how to do that: http://jaapjansma.nl/2015/08/25/howto-setup-a-civicrm-development-environment-for-fixing-bugs/ after you have done so you could start fixing the bug. This bug should probably be fixed in the civicrm-drupal project on github: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal

Comment: Thank you @JaapJansma!  This will be a great project for me.

Comment: Note for myself -- look at line 2182ff in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/modules/views/components/civicrm.core.inc for originally included fields, format examples and probable place to include fixed code.